# I have a problem when Spark connects Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Here is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
                    .appName('Spark') \
                    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers','localhost:9092') \
    .option('subscribe', 'demo') \
    .option("failOnDataLoss","false") \
    .option('startingOffsets', 'earliest') \
    .load()

query = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")\
    .writeStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("topic", "demo-1") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/path/to/HDFS/dir") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

I ran the code with command line: `spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13:3.5.0 mycode.py`
and get the error in `query.awaitTermination()`.
Note: When I use read() instead of readStream() and write() instead of writeStream(), the code run successfully

Comment: The `read() and write()` is for non-stream, so can you post you error info?

Comment: It may help if you could also show the error message in your question. Also, please note that "I have a problem when Spark connects Kafka" isn't a particularly helpful question title. Refer to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on how to write better questions.

Comment: You need to add `kafka-clients` JAR to your packages list for Pyspark

Comment: What is the full error ?

Comment: Here is the error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pathto/mycode.py", line 22, in <module>
    query.awaitTermination()
  File "D:\Program Files\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\streaming\query.py", line 221, in awaitTermination
  File "D:\Program Files\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "D:\Program Files\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py", line 185, in deco`